# Need some help connecting Flask-SQLAlchemy to RDS Proxy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

So I've been running into an error getting a connection from my Flask-SQLAlchemy Module to connect to my RDS proxy. Both the EC2 instance running the python and the DB are setup on the same VPC and I can visualize the DB running a psql command (I'm runnning the Aurora-postgres version on RDS) however cannot connect with my application, always getting this error:

```html
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/psycopg2_patcher.py", line 46, in eventlet_wait_callback
    state = conn.poll()
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Anyone encounter this? Here are my settings for the app.py for the Flask:

```python
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '------------'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 1
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW'] = 0
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# Flask-SQLAlchemy configuration
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = getenv('DATABASE_URL', '-------------------------')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'logs': getenv(getenv('---------'))}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'echo':False,
    'pool_recycle':3600,
    'pool_pre_ping':True,
    'pool_use_lifo':True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the instance can communicate with the RDS Proxy with 5432, but the Proxy communicates with the DB at 3306. SO I just changed the ports in my connection strings back to 5432 and it works perfectly.